# How to read an arbitrary long sequence in lex/yacc with a fixed buffer limit?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I would like to parse / store the following sequence: `Ann {* some arbitrary long sequence *}`

My buffer length (YYLMAX) is set to 8K. Given that the sequence can be arbitrary long, I try to do it this way:

1. Search for the `Ann` token followed by `{*`. Once seen go to a `ANN` state.
2. When in `ANN` state read one character at time until YYLMAX-1. Return this token to YACC which copies/appends it to a C++ string buffer (dynamically increasing).
3. Repeat Step(2) until `*}` is seen. At that point set state to INITIAL (0).

For small sequences (less than 8K), my code works OK. However, if the sequence exceeds 8K the first **grab** works OK, but because it matches the  `annotation_text` rule, the lexer seems to be resetting the state to INITIAL. Thus, as I continue reading the next characters in the sequence, I end up getting a parse error, because the lexer rule `ANN[^*]` no longer matches. I would like to avoid this and remain in the `ANN` state until the full sequence is read until `*}` has been seen. What is the correct way to implement this behavior? A sample example would help.

I don't want to increase the length of YYLMAX because I do not know in advance the maximum length of the sequence inside `Ann {* ... *}` block.

Thank you for any ideas.

The relevant snippet of my YACC grammar looks like this:

```
string curr_annotation = "{*";

annotation            : _STIL_ANN _STIL_ANN_LCURLY annotation_text _STIL_ANN_RCURLY
                        { 
                          curr_annotation += "*}";
                          std::cout << "Going to add annotation '" << curr_annotation << "'" << std::endl;
                          p_block->addAnn(curr_annotation,stil_yylineno);
                          curr_annotation = "{*";
                        }
                      ;
                      
annotation_text       : _STIL_ANN_TEXT
                        {
                          std::cout << "appending to annotation" << std::endl;
                          curr_annotation += $1;
                        }
                      | annotation_text _STIL_ANN_TEXT
                      ;
```

The relevant snippet of my LEXER looks like this:

```
WHITESPACE      [ \t\n\r]
START_BLK_ANN   {WHITESPACE}*"{*"
END_BLK_ANN     "*}"
...

<ANN>{START_BLK_ANN}           { printf("match1\n");
                                 TRACE(("<ANN>START_BLK_ANN <%s> \n",yytext));
                                 return(token(_STIL_ANN_LCURLY));
                               }
<ANN>{END_BLK_ANN}             { printf("match2\n"); TRACE(("<ANN>END_BLK_ANN <%s> \n",yytext));
                                 BEGIN 0;
                                 return(token(_STIL_ANN_RCURLY));
                               } 
<ANN>[^*]                      { printf("match3\n"); yylval.string = stiltok_grab_annotation();
                                 TRACE(("ANN_TEXT <%s> \n",yylval.string));
                                 return(token(_STIL_ANN_TEXT));
                               } 

{IDENTIFIER}                   {
                                 printf("got here\n"); 
                                 temp_sym_name = yytext;
                                 tokVal = stiltoktbl.locateToken(temp_sym_name);
                                 yylval.string = yytext;
                                 if (tokVal != UNDEFINED_TOKEN) {
                                   if (tokVal == _STIL_USER_KEYWORD) {
                                     BEGIN USERKW;
                                     TRACE(("USER_KEYWORD <%s> \n",yytext));
                                   }
                                   else if (tokVal == _STIL_Include)  {
                                     TRACE(("INCLUDE \n"));
                                     BEGIN INCLUDE;
                                     return(token(_STIL_INCLUDE));
                                   }
                                   else if (tokVal == _STIL_Ann) {
                                     TRACE(("ANN \n"));
                                     BEGIN ANN;                   <== Ann Token seen switch state.
                                     return(token(_STIL_ANN));
                                   }
                                   else {
                                     TRACE(("KEYWORD <%s> \n",yytext));
                                   }
                                   return(tokVal);
                                 }
                                 else {
                                   TRACE(("IDENTIFIER <%s> \n",yytext));
                                   return(token(_STIL_IDENTIFIER));
                                 }
```

The `stiltok_grab_annotation` looks like this:

```
char * stiltok_grab_annotation() {

  TRACEID("stiltok_grab_annotation",SEV_4);

  char * p_ann_begin = yytext;  // point past "{*" prefix
  char * p_ann_end   = p_ann_begin + 1;
  char c1 = yyinput();
  char c2 = yyinput();
  *(p_ann_end++) = c1;
  *(p_ann_end++) = c2;
  while ( c1 != '*' || c2 != '}') {
    c1 = c2;
    c2 = yyinput();
    *(p_ann_end++) = c2;
    if ((p_ann_end - yytext) == (MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH-1)) {
       break;
    }
  }
  *(p_ann_end) = '\0';  // place the string terminator at end after "*}" suffix
  
  // Return '*}' token to the lexer  
  if ( c1 == '*' && c2 == '}' ) {
    *(p_ann_end-2) = '\0';
    yyunput(c2, yytext);
    yyunput(c1, yytext);
    
  }

  return p_ann_begin;
}
```

sample run (just the relevant pieces):

```
match1            <-- in ANN state, matched '{*'
Line:[58] {*
match3            <-- in ANN state, matched single character. run stiltok_grab_annotation()...
Line:[58] ......  <-- received 8K-1 characters.

appending to annotation     <-- successfully copied by yacc to string buffer
got here                    <-- lexer has gone back to IDENTIFIER state instead of remaining in ANN state
Line:[58]D_REG55_0_18_0     <-- trouble begins
-S- Parsing error detected in file: x [stilcomyacc_perror]
-T- Syntax Error [Line: 58]
```

Comment: If you're using flex, `YYLMAX` is only used if you use `%array`, and there is no good reason to do that (and lots of good reasons not to, including the fact that the `%array` lexer is significantly slower). Unless you use `REJECT` (again, something to be avoided), flex is very capable of managing its memory, and will probably do a better job that you will. So I'd suggest that you just let flex handle it.

Comment: Also, if you want to stay in `ANN` state, why do you call `BEGIN 0` (which really should be `BEGIN INITIAL`)?